# Padding is missing below the line of communities list on the profile page which displays 0 communities

Tags: support, bug, design, profile-page

Padding is missing under the "Communities" border line, and the list is also showing "**Communities** (0)" (maybe the reason is due to caching as it shows 0 Communities):

[image: communities list without padding]

Generally, padding is present:

[image: communities list with padding]

Answer (score 2):

There are also other users that show as partaking in 0 communities. I just took this screenshot on Stack Overflow:

[image]

This is a new user, and for some other new users it showed that they only joined Stack Overflow, so this well might be a caching error, except for the Community user, who will always be a [Schrödinger's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) user and join all communities and none at the same time.

Comment: This communities list only shows _visible_ communities. You can hide all communities and it’ll show 0. This has nothing to do with caching, as far as I know.

Comment: @SebastianSimon in the meanwhile the user I screenshotted has an update profile, showing one community (SO). So caching might very well be an issue here. I don't expect a new user to start out wIth a hidden profile to later un-hide it.

Comment: I think cache error.  [img](https://imgur.com/a/qb1ix58) & [account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/984181/moodle-learner) & showing **Communities
(1)**